# VBA UserForm design, how to manage the layers of control effectively?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

My Userform has several layers of controls across several tabs on a Tabstrip. I am hiding and showing controls depending on which tab is clicked with the following:

```
Private Sub TabStrip1_Click(ByVal Index As Long)

    WebBrowser1.Visible = (TabStrip1.SelectedItem.Index = 0)
    MultiPage1.Visible = (TabStrip1.SelectedItem.Index = 1)

End Sub
```

This has been working fine up until now, but what I am finding is that the controls are stacking up on top of each other and it is difficult to design. It would be ideal if I could organise it by having hidden controls during the design phase. How do other developers get around this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: `How do other developers get around this issue?` - they get pissed off and switch to [`MultiPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/multipage-control).

Comment: VBA is designed to create controls on the fly rather than hide them. Your code could have all the event procedures for a non-existent textbox, for example, and you create that textbox only when it is needed.

Comment: TabStrip buttons *can* be useful, especially if you use consistent controls with similar Content (otherwise use a `MultiPage` control or create controls on the fly as proposed by comments above :-). - 
Sort of workaround would be to keep the repeating controls where they are, but to design the differing ones 
outside the displayed userform size in a regular distance (e.g.on its right side); each new TabStrip click then would only change these positions
programmatically to move them inside or outside again.

Comment: Hi all, the main controls I have on each tab are webbrowser controls which are not compatible with multipage tabs. Also, thank you for your comments.

Comment: ... and what about one *single* WebBrowser control changing its content only if a TabStrip is clicked? AFAIK it's possible to display Webbrowsers within Multipage pages if they receive content from a (hidden) *parent* WebBrowser placed directly on the UserForm.